# How best to use STIX2 in a document?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, stix

I would like to typeset a document that has both mathematics and English text using the STIX/STIX2 fonts. However I am confused by the various options. First, I assume that STIX2 should be used in preference to STIX (or XITS). However, even after making this assumption, there that are a number of choices, including:

1) Compile using XeLaTeX and include something like the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX2Math}[Extension=.otf]
\setmainfont{STIX2Text}[Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic]
```

2) Another possibility is to compile with any latex (e.g., pdflatex) and start with a preamble like:

```
\usepackage[p,osf]{stickstootext}
\usepackage[stix2,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
```

3) A third possibility is to use the `stix2` package

4) Other options I have missed?

Is there a 'best' approach? Assuming not, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Comment: how I hate the zillions of competing Times clones. see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141033

Comment: @marczellm It's not a Times clone, as you can easily see from this comparison: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Times_and_STIX.png